# why do i keep getting this error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'FarmAnimal&' from an rvalue of type 'FarmAnimal'|

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
class FarmAnimal {
public:
    FarmAnimal(double water_consumption);
    double getwaterConsumption();
    // ...
private:
    double water_consumption;
};

FarmAnimal::FarmAnimal(double water_consumption) {
    this->water_consumption = water_consumption;
}

double FarmAnimal::getwaterConsumption() {
    return water_consumption;
}

class ConsumptionAccumulator
{

public: ConsumptionAccumulator();
      double getTotalConsumption();
      void addConsumption(FarmAnimal& animal);
private:
    double total_consumption;
};

ConsumptionAccumulator::ConsumptionAccumulator() :
    total_consumption(0)
{
}

double ConsumptionAccumulator::getTotalConsumption()
{
    return total_consumption;
}

void ConsumptionAccumulator::addConsumption(FarmAnimal& animal)
{

    total_consumption += animal.getwaterConsumption();
}

class Cow : public FarmAnimal
{
    public: Cow(double weigth) : FarmAnimal(0.086 * weigth) {}
};

class Sheep : public FarmAnimal {
public:
    Sheep(double weigth) : FarmAnimal(0.11 * weigth) {}
};

class Horse : public FarmAnimal {
public:
    Horse(double weigth) : FarmAnimal(0.068 * weigth) {}
}; 

int main()
{
    ConsumptionAccumulator accumulator;
    double weigth = 0;
    std::string input = "";
    do
    {
        std::getline(cin, input);
        if (1 == sscanf(input.c_str(), "cow %lf", &weigth))
        {
            accumulator.addConsumption((Cow)(weigth));
        }
        else if (1 == sscanf(input.c_str(), "sheep% lf", &weigth))
        {
            accumulator.addConsumption(Sheep(weigth));
        }
        else if (1 == sscanf(input.c_str(), "horse% lf", &weigth))
        {
            accumulator.addConsumption(Horse(weigth));
        }
    } while (input != "");
    cout << accumulator.getTotalConsumption() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
void ConsumptionAccumulator::addConsumption(FarmAnimal& animal)
{
    total_consumption += animal.getwaterConsumption();
}
```

to this

```
void ConsumptionAccumulator::addConsumption(const FarmAnimal& animal)
{
    total_consumption += animal.getwaterConsumption();
}
```

C++ has a rule that you cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary object. When you call `addConsumption` here

```
accumulator.addConsumption((Cow)(weigth));
```

you are creating a temporary `Cow` object and trying to use that to call `addConsumption` but it doesn't work because of the rule I mentioned.

Don't ignore `const` in C++. Use const references when you can, and declare methods as const if that's what they are.

Comment: after doing this i got this error   passing 'const FarmAnimal' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|

Comment: That's because you also need to declare `getwaterConsumption` as a const method. Like I said above, you cannot ignore const in C++. Go through all your getters and declare them as const methods.